# Multiple datasources and multiple profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two profiles ("autoContido" and "weblogic") and each one of these profiles has two configuration classes, due to the fact that i'm using two datasources.

I have annotated the beans from a specific datasource as @Primary and the beans from the other datasource configuration class aren't @Primary but i named them differently.

I thought that by using @Primary annotations there wouldn't be errors like the one below, but i'm still getting them. Can anyone help me to see what the problem is?

```
"Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.brb.maf.model.repository.impl.EmprestimoTelebancoRepositoryImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null"
```

I tried using @Primary annotation but i'm still getting the error Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.brb.maf.model.repository.impl.EmprestimoTelebancoRepositoryImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"br.com.brb.maf.model.pesquisa.repository"},
        transactionManagerRef = "customMobileTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mobileEntityManager")
@Profile("weblogic")
public class BanknetDatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

 //ommited ...

@Value("${spring.datasource.mobile.jndi-name}")
    private String mobileJndiName;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES);
        this.dataSourcePropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_DATASOURCE);
    }

    @Bean(name = "customMobileTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("mobileEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mobileDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(mobileJndiName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mobileEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("mobileDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.brb.maf.model.pesquisa"});

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, VALIDATE));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"br.com.brb.maf.model.repository"},
        transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@Profile("weblogic")
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

//ommited...

@Value("${spring.datasource.maf.jndi-name}")
    private String mafJndiName;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES);
        this.dataSourcePropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_DATASOURCE);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.brb.maf.model"});

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        // DataSource dataSource =
        // dsLookup.getDataSource(dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty(JNDI_NAME));
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(mafJndiName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "customTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, VALIDATE));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = { "br.com.brb.maf.model.pesquisa.repository" })
@Profile("autoContido")
public class BanknetDatabaseConfigurationStandalone implements EnvironmentAware {

//ommited...

@Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES);
        new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_DATASOURCE);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mobileDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.mobile")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mobileEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("mobileDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.brb.maf.model.pesquisa"});

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, VALIDATE));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = { "br.com.brb.maf.model.repository" })
@Profile("autoContido")
public class DatabaseConfigurationStandalone implements EnvironmentAware {

//ommited...

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.jpaPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES);
        new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, SPRING_DATASOURCE);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.maf")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"br.com.brb.maf.model"});

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, VALIDATE));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                jpaPropertyResolver.getProperty(HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryImpl implements EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryCustom {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryImpl(EntityManager manager) {
        this.entityManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime ultimaDataPesquisa() {
        String jpql = "Select distinct max(i.dataOcorrencia) from IndicioEmprestimoBanknet i ";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        return (LocalDateTime) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
15165 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emprestimoJobTelebancoScheduler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'telebancoJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'EmprestimoTelebancoJob' defined in class path resource [br/com/brb/maf/application/batch/emprestimo/telebanco/EmprestimoTelebancoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'emprestimoTelebancoJob' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'EmprestimoTelebancoJobStep' defined in class path resource [br/com/brb/maf/application/batch/emprestimo/telebanco/EmprestimoTelebancoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emprestimoTelebancoReader': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emprestimoServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'telebancoRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emprestimoTelebancoRepositoryImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\u840280\Desktop\SVN\MAF\backend\construcao\branches\DSV_1.0.7\fontes\target\classes\br\com\brb\maf\model\repository\impl\EmprestimoTelebancoRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1 
15181 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
15181 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
15212 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
15228 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.brb.maf.model.repository.impl.EmprestimoTelebancoRepositoryImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null
    - org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1: defined by method 'createSharedEntityManager' in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I just had to explicitly set which EnityManager i'd use in EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryImpl. So, in the end, it had to be like below:

```
@Repository
public class EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryImpl implements EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryCustom {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public EmprestimoBanknetRepositoryImpl(@Qualifier("mobileEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager manager) {
        this.entityManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime ultimaDataPesquisa() {
        String jpql = "Select distinct max(i.dataOcorrencia) from IndicioEmprestimoBanknet i ";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
        return (LocalDateTime) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Comment: I figured out, that the `@Qualifier` annotation is not working with Lombok. You have to create the constructor explicitly and add `@Qualifier` to the constructor parameter - like in this example. `@Qualifier` does not work on the field!

Answer (score 0):

To me the main thing that stands out is that you're not defining the transaction and entity manager references in the standalone configurations when defining the repositories via the EnableJpaRepositories annotation, but you do so in the standard ones.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = { "br.com.brb.maf.model.repository" }
)
@Profile("autoContido")
public class DatabaseConfigurationStandalone implements EnvironmentAware
```

If you're using Hibernate then the managers can be the same bean, so just move the @Profile annotation from the configuration to only the DataSource beans.

Here's an example of using 2 data sources: [Spring JPA – Multiple Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)
Making this work with multiple profiles should be as easy as adding a @Profile annotation to every configuration class, just make sure they the other annotations are the same.

Comment: Initially, i thought it would be that. But it turned out it was something else. I posted the answer. Thanks fot the help